# Sending pictures/images to remote database

Tags: camera

Good day, First ever question on this forum.

I have a Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2 and my Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to the internet.

I want to send the images captured by the camera to an online database upon taking the picture.

I also want to enter meta data details with the image such as the time it was taken alongside the data, etc...

My question is:

Is there a way I can do this via python? (if so, is it recommended? Built in methods in Python? or a library?) or, it would be better to install an Apache server and use PHP code and do a cron job that always checks the specific folder the images are saved if they get any new files saved, get the images to send and insert to online DB.

To complete the idea and further explain the process; from the remote server, using PHP I will be sending a push notification to an android phone which would contain the URL of image on the remote server so that the person sees the image.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough in Python. See [capturing to a network stream](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream) for an example of sending individual images over a network socket (you can add whatever metadata you want to the protocol which is just "length" "image" "length" "image"... in the recipe).

As for storing in a database, Python has [SQLite3 built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) which might be sufficient for your case, or you could use a "proper" database server like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), or you could just use the file-system (with some care). Incidentally, there's also a (basic) [HTTP server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) built into Python.